# want to add image in mail body PHP

Tags: php, email, yii

This is code i use to send image in mail body

```
    $message2 .= '<div style = "color: white; padding: 5px;"></div></div>';

    # Open a file
    $url = realpath(Yii::app()->theme->basePath) . "/images/Male-icon.png";
    $file = fopen($url, "r");
    if ($file == false) {
        echo "Error in opening file";
        exit();
    }
    # Read the file into a variable
    $size = filesize($url);
    $content = fread($file, $size);

    # encode the data for safe transit
    # and insert \r\n after every 76 chars.
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

    # Get a random 32 bit number using time() as seed.
    $num = md5(time());

    # Define the main headers.
    $header = "From:xyz@somedomain.com\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
    $header .= "boundary=$num\r\n";
    $header .= "--$num\r\n";

    # Define the message section
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n\n";
    $header .= "$message2\r\n";
    $header .= "--$num\r\n";

    # Define the attachment section
    //$header .= "Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; ";
    $header .= "Content-Type:  image/jpeg; ";
    $header .= "name=\"Male-icon.png\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
    $header .= "filename=\Male-icon.png\"\r\n\n";
    $header .= "$encoded_content\r\n";
    $header .= "--$num--";

    # Send email now
    $retval = mail($to, $subject, "", $header);
    if ($retval == true) {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
    } else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
    }
```

I am using simple mail function send image in mail body. help to solve my problem. In gmail it added underscore automatically  image cant be viewed. guide me how is it possible to send image in mail body.

Comment: why are you using encoded contents? Just use the image full url in src attribue of img tag. e.g. <img src="full_url_of_image"

Comment: i am using this also though not working   $message2 .= '<div style = "color: white"><img src="' . realpath(Yii::app()->theme->basePath) . '/images/Male-icon.png" width="30px;" /><h1>iqloads.com</h1></div>';

Comment: dont use realpath, use full url like http://www.yoursite.com/.....